# Correct proverbial anecdote for: To fix a bucket, I need a bucket

Tags: proverbs

An proverbial anecdote I've heard for a problem solving deadlock is something along the lines of:

> A farmer needs to fix a bucket, which requires *this*, that then
>   requires *that* and so on and so forth until it requires a bucket to
>   fix the bucket.

However I haven't been able to find this particular proverbial anecdote for a problem solving deadlock, so I'm wondering:

*What is the most common (folksy?) proverbial anecdote for describing a problem solving deadlock?*

Comment: [There's a hole in my bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket)

Comment: @andy256 Excellent. I think that's exactly the proverb/anecdote I heard. Care to submit that as an answer?

Comment: I thought that _catch-22_ could be a type of deadlock, but in consideration the regulations regarding sanity in warfare in the book Catch-22 were deliberately contrived by the faceless antagonists to reduce medical discharges, so not really a normal problem solving deadlock nor anecdote to that effect. More of a forked-path resolution paradox as described by the honorable _Josh61_.

Comment: I haven't come up with a good or well-known proverb for this deadlock situation, but the general process of endlessly branching tangents one is forced to follow in pursuing an objective ("To fix my bucket I needed a knife, to sharpen my knife I needed a stone; to wet the stone I needed some water...") is known as [***yak-shaving***](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YakShavingDefinedIllGetThatDoneAsSoonAsIShaveThisYak.aspx).

Comment: There's always "You can't get there from here."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's a hole in my bucket** is a folk song describing a circular set of requirements. It describes a situation where there is a hole in the bucket, but fixing the hole requires straw, cutting the straw requires (in the version I learned) an axe, but the axe is blunt and needs sharpening. Finally the sharpening stone needs water, but there's a **hole in the bucket**.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket) article suggests that songs of this type date from c1700.

Comment: The other answers are nice; but only this one refers to a deadlock of a circular prerequisite. Admittedly, given many stack exchange members have an IT background, we often think of multi-threaded deadlocks because imperative programming catches single-thread cyclic deadlocks which _A Hole in the Bucket_ is.

Answer (score 2):

A *[no-win situation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation)*, (also called a “*lose-lose situation*”) is a common way to express the concept of a deadlock situation:

> - is one where a person has choices, but no choice leads to a net gain. For example, if an executioner offers the condemned the choice of dying by being hanged, shot, or poisoned, since all choices lead to death, the condemned is in a no-win situation. This bleak situation gives the chooser little room: whatever choice is made, the person making it will lose their life.
>
>   - Less drastic situations might also be considered no-win situations: if one has a choice for lunch between a ham sandwich and a roast beef sandwich, but is a vegetarian or has a wheat allergy, that might be considered a no-win situation.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no-win%20situation%2Close-lose%20situation%2Ccatch%2022&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20-%20win%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Close%20-%20lose%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccatch%2022%3B%2Cc0) no-win/lose-lose/catch 22.

Other ways to express similar or related  concepts are: (from Wikipedia)

> - Cornelian dilemma
> - Double bind
> - Kobayashi Maru
> - Morton's fork
> - Pyrrhic victory

Comment: My fault for using the term _catch-22_ liberally. Strictly speaking I'm looking for a solution deadlock than a general forked-path contradiction. Still, it's an answer to the question as initially worded. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Until I just looked it up, I always assumed...

> [First catch your hare](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ogm0c8mYtQUC&pg=PT262&dq=%22first%20catch%20your%20hare%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IRdpVPSEGpDwaOWigLgI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22first%20catch%20your%20hare%22&f=false)

...came from *Mrs Beeton's Book of Household Management (1851)*. Or at least some similar candidate, such as *Mrs Glasse's Art of Cookery (1747)*. I've lost count of the number of people telling me *catching = removing the skin of* the hare before it's cooked. But idiomatically it's often used figuratively of the need to *get hold of* a live fleeing hare before you can even start *thinking* about how to prepare it for the table.

---

That's not exactly *"In order to fix this **broken** X I need a **working** X (but the only available X is this broken one which I'm not equipped to fix)"*. But we do have various "reduplicative" saying like *"It takes a thief to catch a thief"*, *"Handsome is as handsome does"*, etc. Arguably the most relevant one (with many minor variations) is...

> [You need money to make money](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22first%20catch%20your%20hare%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22need%20money%20to%20make%20money%22)

---

I'll remove this if people think it should stand as a separate answer, but @andy256's link to [There's a hole in my bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Hole_in_My_Bucket) is certainly relevant (it's a nursery rhyme that starts with the need to fix the bucket, and after an indeterminate number of verses ends with lack of a functional bucket preventing steps from being taken to fix it). But I can't say I've often (if ever) heard it used as a conversational allusion in the context of a real-world "need X to get/fix X" dilemma.